# How to configure Apache drill within eclipse data source explorer

Tags: eclipse, apache-drill

I successfully configured apache drill in squirrel sql client. But would like to use eclipse datasource explorer. It allows me to create connection but when it connects seems to be hung. I use drill 1.6 and eclipse mars. Please help or suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drill JDBC driver as any other JDBC driver with Eclipse Datasource Explorer. You can find all other configs in Drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/#example-of-connecting-to-drill-programmatically).